# Magnetic field of a solenoid at the poles?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

It's known that at the center of an electromagnet/solenoid the magnetic field $B$ is strongest there. At the pole/edge of the solenoid/ or electromagnet is the magnetic field $B$ strong? Let's assume $B$ = $1$ tesla at the center, how different is $B$ at the edges?

[image]
<sub>(source: [gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/imgmag/barsol.gif))</sub>

In general, is it simple to create a $1$ tesla magnetic field or higher? 
MRI's use field's above $4$ tesla yet it seems very complex and requires massive power & cooling.

Comment: Provided that the solenoid is sufficiently long (i.e., radius$\ll$length), it should be about a half of the field at the center. One can see this by noting that the upper and lower halves of the solenoid contribute equally to the field at center. If you remove one of them, you only have one half of the original B field.

Comment: @higgsss What if the solenoid was not that long? Quite short in length and large in radius. It seems that it might be simple and possible to create a powerful electromagnet and the poles are near a $Tesla$ .

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of a circular current thread lying in the y,z-plane with center at the origin is given as $B = \frac{\mu I}{2} \frac{R^2}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ on the x-axis at the coordinate value $x$. The B-field is aligned to the x-axis. The direction of rotation of the current flow and the direction of the B-field build a right-handed screw.

We integrate this to find the B-field on the x-axis at the coordinate $x$ for a solenoid with $n$ windings of current $I$, and with the x-axis as its symmetry axis.
The current flow is modelled as uniform current distribution of strength $\frac{nI}{L}$ on a cylinder surface with radius $R$ starting at $x_{\rm coil}=0$ and ending at $L$.
The result of the integration is:
$$B = \frac{\mu n I}{2L} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}} + \frac{(L-x)}{\sqrt{(L-x)^2+R^2}}\right].$$

Now at the ends the field is simply 
$$B_{\rm end} = \frac{\mu n I}{2\sqrt{L^2+R^2}}$$

At the middle of the coil the field on the x-axis is
$$
B_{\rm middle} = \frac{\mu n I}{2\sqrt{\left(\frac L2\right)^2+R^2}}
$$
Note : There is no change in material (permeability)
Here $\mu = \mu_r \mu_0 = k \mu_0$ and $n$ is no of turns per unit length.

In an MRI scanner the fields are produced around objects which are not in contact ! i.e. The fields have strengths ranging from 1 to 7 T in air, it is not very difficult to produce these fields in material like iron as they boost magnetic fields by factors of 1000. But to make such fields in air 1000 times energy is required and therefore these scanners utilise high power, coolants and nowadays superconducting wires too.

Addendum :
For an example (as requested in comments), suppose a solenoid of length $1 m$ and radius of cross section $0.1m$, having $1000$ no of turns per unit length($1 m$) carrying current $1 A$ and filled with air which makes $\mu = \mu_0$. Then, 
$$B = \frac{1000\mu_0}{2} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+0.1^2}} + \frac{(1-x)}{\sqrt{(1-x)^2+0.1^2}}\right].$$
$$B_{\rm end} = \frac{1000\mu_0}{2\sqrt{1^2+0.1^2}}$$
$$B_{\rm end} = 0.0025008012 T$$
$$B_{\rm middle} = \frac{1000\mu_0}{2\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+0.1^2}}$$
$$B_{\rm middle} = 0.0049289361 T$$

Comment: Note, iron saturates above 2T. This makes 7T difficult.

Comment: @Tobias : I have not mentioned fields of 7T in iron, I have mentioned the upper limit of today's mri scanner
field. I haven't talked about how it is achieved ! Also the formulae were correct before too as at that time $n$ was loops per unit length and now it is total no. of loops, thanks anyway for the edit !

Comment: @rijulgupta Could you please use an example to illustrate this, I did a few calculations but not sure of my values are correct... But could you use k in the formula of B.end?

Comment: @rijulgupta  L = The length of the whole wire used to create the total number of turns correct? So 1 meter for that wire is used to created n # of turns?

Comment: @Key : yes ! Was there any confusion or were you just clarifying ? Btw why haven't you accepted the answer if yoj are satisfied ?

Comment: No no I am completely satisfied!

Comment: @rijulgupta I'm wondering... Since I'm using a 4 AWG copper wire for lower resistance, to cover a cylinder iron core that's area is equal to 0.032, radius = 0.101m, how long of a wire is needed... 10 meters maybe? To achieve 1000 turns.

Comment: That's simple algebra !. Length of one loop * no of loops. Use $ 2\pi r n$ for your specifications,n got $634.6 m$

Comment: @rijulgupta 634.6m?! That's too much, it's almost 0.6km  that's an extremely long wire to wrap around a cylinder ferromagnet a 1000 turns!

Comment: Well length of wire for each loop is approx. 0.6m, so what did you expect !

Comment: @rijulgupta does k  depend on the size of the iron? The larger it is, the more k is rated? I mean is k = 1000 from a small piece of iron?

Comment: It is independent of size, but I would expect unequalities and uneavenness in the k values over any piece of iron. Overall it would be in a nearby range.

Comment: Are there core's where $k$ exceeds $5000$, and saturates at $2 Tesla?$

Comment: @rijulgupta Finally, what do you think the magnitude of the repulsive force and attractive forces of such a solenoid of $ 1 Tesla$ introduced to a similar solenoid  ?

Comment: @rijulgupta what is you input from my question above?

Comment: why do you integrate B wrt x to go from the middle to the edge of the coil? wouldn't that create a different thing that we are measuring, i,e. B dx?

Comment: Why so many significant figures.. that’s normally considered poor form?

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, it is actually N in the final formula, not n! The formula with "n = N/L" in it is wrong, you basically replace N/L with N/2*sqrt(L^2+R^2) for the end of the solenoid.