# Magnetic field at the center and ends of a long solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

A long solenoid has current $I$ flowing through it, also denote $N$ as the turns per unit length. Take its axis to be the $z$-axis, by symmetry the only component of the magnetic field inside is $B_z$. Find the magnetic field at the center of the solenoid (on the axis). Also, find the magnetic field at the ends of the solenoid.

For the first part, since the solenoid is long we can approximate the magnetic field inside to be uniform and is given by $B_z = μ_0NI$, so we can say that the magnetic field at the center is also $μ_0NI$. I'm not sure if my argument is correct but based on my understanding, from the uniformity of the $B$-field inside, it should be the same everywhere inside. Can anyone kindly tell me if this is correct? Any suggestions and insights?

For the second part I don't have any idea on how to start.

Comment: The answer to this question may be useful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95725/magnetic-field-of-a-solenoid-at-the-poles

Comment: @tmwilson26 Can you expound on the explanation that the user higgsss gave? What is the relationship of the field at the ends to the center?

Comment: The way he did it, he found the field for a single loop at a distance $z$ from the center of the loop on axis.  He then integrated the field of many loops at different positions.  He started at $z=0$ and ended at $z=L$ for his integrals.  If you are doing the long solenoid approximation, you can take the limit of $L\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @tmwilson26 Thank you for the clarification! So the field at both ends of the solenoid is half of the field at the center? But is my answer for the first part correct? The field at the center of a LONG solenoid is the same field everywhere inside, which is μNI? So that the field at both ends are μNI/2.

Comment: Yes, those are the correct relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, the magnetic field at some internal point on the axis of a solenoid is given by general expression 
$$B=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2}(\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2)$$
where, $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$ are the angles between axis & the lines joining the extreme-points of both the ends of solenoid to the concerned point.

1) magnetic field at the center of a long solenoid is given by setting $\theta_1=0$ & $\theta_2=\pi$ $$B=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2}(\cos 0-\cos\pi)=\color{blue}{\mu_0 NI}$$

2) magnetic field at the end of a long solenoid is given by setting $\theta_1=\pi/2$ & $\theta_2=\pi$ $$B=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2}(\cos \pi/2-\cos\pi)=\color{blue}{\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2}}$$

Thus, the magnetic field at the center of a long solenoid is two times the magnetic field at the ends .

Comment: What is$N$ here? Is it number of turns or number of turns per unit length?

Comment: N is the number of turns per unit length.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Can you please include or add a source for the derivation of that general formula please ? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

since you are concerned about a *long* solenoid, this problem has a very simple solution.

Suppose you have two identical long solenoids, each of them having magnetic field $B$ at the ends. You join them end to end, such that their magnetic moments are in same direction. Thus, at the junction the magnetic field adds up to $B+B=2B$.

But this junction is nothing but the mid point of another *long* sloenoid, with same value of *N*. Thus we get $μNI=2B$, or $B=μNI/2 $!