# burning candle flame disturbed by unseen force .What could this force be?

Tags: visible-light

If a burning candle were placed in a enclosed glass box with a sufficient amount of oxygen to stay ignited, What outside source could interact with the flame causing a disturbance?

Comment: Do you have photo/video of what kind of disturbance you're talking about? There are multiple hydrodynamic instabilities that form around jets, plumes, and other buoyant flows and so it would be easier to identify which instability you are referring to by seeing it.

Comment: If the glass box is small enough, it could simply be the result of convection.

Comment: No convection because this interaction can happen at will

Comment: @Peltio maybe. But convection currents in a closed cell are usually (never?) pulsatile in nature, right? Flickering is clearly a (strong) pulsatile phenomena. Now if the convection currents carried varying composition of oxygen to the base of the flame - but I don't believe this likely.

Comment: @Peltio it has to be a more local phenomena. See my updated answer below - and regarding feedback, limit cycles

Comment: @docscience The convection currents could cause intermittent turbulence which could show "random" or "at will" fluctuations. We don't know what the "at will" interaction looks like, but I would assume it isn't periodic/sustained.

Comment: @docscience: the gas set in motion by convection would hit the boundaries of the container and from them on it might turn chaotic (for several reasons). You might try to see if there is a difference between the behavior in small and big glass enclosures.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the observed 'flickering' of a candle flame you can refer [here](http://candles.org/candle-science/) as to the basic reason why flicker occurs as well as other physical characteristics of candle flames.

The flame is essentially the outcome of a chemical reaction - a fuel being oxidized that leads to products of water, carbon dioxide, heat and light - and if the reaction is sometimes incomplete - elemental carbon (soot).

But the basic reason for flicker has to do with *not* having consistent rate of this chemical reaction. If either the fuel (molten candle wax) or oxidizer have momentary variations in the rate at which they supply the reaction, then the reaction can momentarily slow down, causing the flame to weaken in intensity.

You mention the steady supply of oxygen, but you also need a steady supply of molten wax which is self-supplied by the melting of the flame and the wicking of the molten wax through an imperfect microstructure fiber network of the candle wick. The rate at which wax moves through that wick is determined by those fiber properties, but also any differential pressure, presumably set up by surface tension forces between the fibers and the molten wax, and probably also the temperature differences between the wax pool and the tip of the wick within the candle's flame.

But that's not the only variation to be expected. Even though you may attempt to maintain a constant supply of oxygen within the flame, the inside of a closed container and heating of the gas will lead to convection and eddy currents. This will ultimately lead to variations of oxygen being supplied to the flame - and therefore variations in the rate of chemical reaction and flame strength.

There could also be a (positive) feedback effect that mediates through local temperature variations at the base of the flame. Heat may spur a sudden surge of molten wax fuel into the flame which leads to a mixture ratio that cuts temperature and slows the surge. Thus you would have a [limit cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) - a nonlinear oscillation. One could design an experiment that tests this hypothesis by preparing a set of candles that progressively have longer wicks. This would adjust the base of the flame to be closer or farther away from the wax pool. By doing this one may be able to observe the onset/absence of flickers, and perhaps even different flicker rates as a function of the wick length.

But no matter how hard you try to keep things perfect and still the harsh realities of nature will intrude and spoil your efforts.

Comment: No this is a force that can interact with the flame at will.

Comment: Could a electric magnetic field be the disturbance? This is my theory.

Comment: All matter is to some extent diamagnetic (even oxygen), and so yes if you were to obtain a device that can exert a *strong* fluctuating magnetic field you might be able to influence the flame. But if you are referring to the natural magnetic field that the earth exerts, then probably no. That field is so weak and essentially static at any one point on the earth where you might run your experiment.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly either hydrodynamic instabilities or heterogeneity in the fuel supply. There's no magnetic field effects unless you happen to put giant magnets around the box.

Comment: @tpg2114 I agree - with the magnetic field conclusion. But as far as the fuel supply, even if the solid wax has local heterogeneous composition, the fuel that burns comes from the molten wax pool, where differences would have plenty of time to mix before being wicked up.

Comment: @docscience I totally agree with that -- but it's easy to simulate perfect fuels with computers and even in that case you would still see some flickering. That's why I wanted a picture, it would be easier to see what kind of instability was being referred to.

Comment: tpg2114 the reaction is caused when a certain force is applied to the fire it is controlled the disturbance is not spontaneous.But if a magnetic field is the only cause without physical interaction to the flame it must be the answer.

Comment: I will post a video to this post by the end of the day

Comment: @tpg2114 see my update - edits. Perhaps the flicker can be explained by a thermal limit cycle

Comment: @Mr.Who I will await the video to see it. However, unless you are doing some *really* crazy, it is not magnetic fields. How crazy? The Earth's magnetic field is 10s of microteslas. [To see a flame bend in an asymmetric magnetic field](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jap/65/3/10.1063/1.343016), they are talking about applying entire Teslas. As in 100000 times stronger than the Earth's field. You can [actually make magnets this strong](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/1-tesla-electromagnet) if you wanted to see what magnetic fields really did to flames.

Comment: The bright part of fire is plasma. The rapidly oxidizing fuel generates enough heat to transform the gaseous byproducts and the nearby air into plasma. Because plasma is made of positive ions and free electrons, it can react to the magnetic field just like many metals do.

Comment: @Mr.Who I don't disagree. I have studied MHD effects on combustion -- combustion is a field I understand very well. However, ambient magnetic fields are not strong enough for a candle flame. Unless you are specifically forcing it or living inside an MRI machine, the magnetic fields are not strong enough to cause disturbances.

Comment: Tpg2114 then what else can this unseen force be? Intermolecular forces?

Comment: @Mr.Who but tpg2114 is right - the Earth's magnetic field is just way too weak to affect the flame or the reactants and products of the flame's chemical reaction - including the ions you cite - furthermore the Earth's field does not oscillate anywhere nearly as fast as the flame oscillates.

Comment: @Mr.Who more likely a local thermal limit cycle oscillation.

Comment: @Mr.Who This answer covers it -- 1. Fuel heterogeneity (no candle you every burn will be perfect). 2. Hydrodynamic instability (every jet and plume becomes unstable no matter how still the ambient air). 3. Recirculation within the box -- the flame makes air rise so it has to sink somewhere, and this can create intermittent turbulence which will make the flame wobble "at will" or randomly. 4. The ambient air inside the box is not still -- unless you put your box there and let it sit for many hours, there will be turbulence inside the box.

Comment: the box was to show there was not outside interference like wind, the same process happens without the box too.It is a controlled experiment meaning the unknown disturbance can be stopped.It is not a random affect.